# React. State does not change after change select

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the event, I change select element and call the data update method.
The method takes values from state. But it turns out when the data is updated, state has not been changed yet.
When you call the data update again, the state has already been updated
How to do the update correctly?

**React component**

```
  const [dataList, setdataList] = useState([]);
  const [isLoding, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [minPaid, setMinPaid] = useState(0);

  const dataSelectList = [
    { label: "2", value: "20000000" },
    { label: "3", value: "30000000" },
    { label: "4", value: "40000000" },
    { label: "5", value: "50000000" },
    { label: "10", value: "100000000" },
  ];

  const LoadData = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    fetch("url", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        paid: minPaid,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        if (data.success)
            setdataList(data.list);
      });
  };

  

  const onChange = (selectedOption) => {
    setMinPaid(parseInt(selectedOption.value));
    LoadData();
  };

  return (
    <div>      
        <Select              
          options={dataList}
          onChange={onChange.bind(this)}
        />          
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple 'what' factores for me. For once, you have an function called loadData, which performs a POST...

Another thing I saw, is;

```js
<Select              
          options={dataList}
          onChange={onChange.bind(this)}
        />
```

has a `bind`, I do not think that's necessary, instead, I'd change it to be

```js
<Select              
          options={dataList}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
```

### The main problem.

also, when you're performing state changes, and then calling a function, the state change may not be updated when the fetch is called.

```
const onChange = (selectedOption) => {
    setMinPaid(parseInt(selectedOption.value));
    LoadData();
  };
```

So I think it's better to pass that value to the LoadData function instead like this:

```js
 const [dataList, setdataList] = useState([]);
  const [isLoding, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [minPaid, setMinPaid] = useState(0);

  const dataSelectList = [
    { label: "2", value: "20000000" },
    { label: "3", value: "30000000" },
    { label: "4", value: "40000000" },
    { label: "5", value: "50000000" },
    { label: "10", value: "100000000" },
  ];

  const LoadData = (minPaid) => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    fetch("url", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        paid: minPaid,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        if (data.success)
            setdataList(data.list);
      });
  };

  

  const onChange = (selectedOption) => {
    setMinPaid(parseInt(selectedOption.value));
    LoadData(parseInt(selectedOption.value));
  };

  return (
    <div>      
        <Select              
          options={dataList}
          onChange={onChange}
        />          
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: what's wrong with bind? Where I read it was recommended for event transmission.

Comment: Passing a parameter to a method is of course the solution. But I would like to understand and understand what the problem is and how to solve this problem through the state

Comment: When you update a state, the whole component needs to rerender for the new state to be set. When you're firing a function, right after, the minPaid state is not changed yet. So in theory you're calling the function with the old value.

Comment: The bind thing, was something we did when class component was the way of making statefull components. Now, when we have functional components that also can use state. We do not need to bind our onChange events with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify  `setMinPaid(parseInt(selectedOption.value))` to  `setMinPaid(parseInt(selectedOption.target.value))` instead.